# How to mock a function which returns a promise and verify it with exact arguments

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon, es6-promise

I want to mock a Database call which returns a promise. And then I want to verify whether it is called with exact arguments or not.

```
func(data) {
  let formattedData = formatData(data);
  return DbClient.saveData(formattedData).then(() => {
      return { "ok": true }
  }).catch(() => {
      return { "ok": false }
  });
}
```

and my test case is

```
it("", (done) => {
   let dbMock = sinon.mock(DbClient).expects("saveData");
   dbMock.returns(Promise.resolve({ "ok": true }));
   dbMock.withExactArgs(formattedData);  
   func(data).then(resp => {
      try{
         dbMock.verify();
         expect(resp).to.deep.equal({ "ok": true });
         done();
      } catch(err) {
         done(err);
      }
   })
});
```

The promise is not resolving when I use `dbMock.withExactArgs(formattedData)`

If I give the proper `formattedData` then it is getting passed, when I tried to fail the test with some other args instead of `formattedData` the promise is not resolving so I'm getting this error:

`Error: timeout of 3000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`

** when I remove the `dbMock.withExactArgs(formattedData)` my test is passing, since the mock is resolving the promise.

Answer (score 0):

I've replicated what you describe, using your code and adding code based on your description. The only problem in the code you show is that `func` is not returning its promise. You need:

```
function func(data) {
  let formattedData = formatData(data);
  return DbClient.saveData(formattedData).then(() => {
      return { "ok": true }
  }).catch(() => {
      return { "ok": false }
  });
}
```

Comment: actually my func is returning a promise, which I forgot to mention in the code[updated now]. But still I'm having the same problem, it is waiting for the promise to resolve or reject as mentioned in the question.